# Error in SciPy installation in Windows 64-bit using pip

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, numpy, pip

I am a rookie in using Python. I have python 2.7 installed in my windows 64-bit computer. When I try to install `scipy` using pip, I am getting this error:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install scipy
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-0.19.0.zip
Installing collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py install for scipy ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\vamshi\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-nqaj7b\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\vamshi\appdata\local\temp\pip-7jix0g-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
```

Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

```
  - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source release)
  - `pip install scipy`   (last SciPy release on PyPI)


lapack_opt_info:
lapack_mkl_info:
  libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python27\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_lapack_info:
  libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python27\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE
```

Can somebody tell me, why is this happening and what may be the reason and how can I correct it.

Comment: I recommend you to install anaconda package (https://www.continuum.io/downloads), it has all you need to start working with python.

Answer (score 0):

`scipy` relies on other packages.  From the error, you are missing `mkl` and `openblas`.  As @Paddy recommended, using conda makes installation much easier because it handles all of the package dependencies for you.

You can either uninstall your current version of Python and install [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) which comes with conda and a large number of other packages including `scipy`.

Or you can install miniconda, which adds conda to your current setup.